# appsettings.json file is accessible when publishing Blazor WASM app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app and I have a sensitive data in appsettings.json

Problem is that when publishing the Blazor WASM app , the appsettings.json file is accessible for the clients to download and access it

how to prevent certain type of action?

Comment: You cannot, everything will be accessible in WASM.

Comment: As RBee says, the whole of you WASM code is an open book to anyone with the right tools.  So either your sensitive stuff should be in the API, or your app isn't suitable for WASM.